# Don't Allow Users to Edit Pages

Tags: pages

Does anyone know how to disable users from editing pages? I have tried "stop inheriting" on Site Pages but that doesn't work.  Users are still able to edit pages. I created a new permission group where List Permission are set to add, edit, delete, view, open items and Site permissions are set to browse directories, view pages, browse user information, Use Remote Interface, Use Client Integration Features and Open. This still isn't working. Does someone know why?

Comment: Once you stop inheriting, did you then remove the persons/groups from the Site Pages list.  Usually i'll just remove all but the admin group and then grant all users read access.

Comment: You don't have to create a new permission set in order to prevent users from editing the pages. Break the permissions om the pages library and change the permissions of the members group from contribute to read. Ensure that the users are not member of any other group, like owners